# access 2010 how to check if yes/no field is checked

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I keep getting this error:

> Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

With this sql statement:

```
SELECT CD_BAN 
            FROM Tbl_Clients
            WHERE EXISTS = Yes
```

EXIST is a yes/no field..

I am using php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EXISTS` is a keyword.  If that is also your field name, bracket it to avoid confusing the db engine.

```
SELECT CD_BAN 
FROM Tbl_Clients
WHERE [EXISTS] = True
```

Or you could qualify it with the table name instead.

```
SELECT Tbl_Clients.CD_BAN 
FROM Tbl_Clients
WHERE Tbl_Clients.EXISTS = True
```